# PowerShell Script to copy file to multiple folders listed in text or csv file

Tags: powershell, file, directory

I want to copy a file to multiple folders, folders are listed in a text file.  Noob to PS, appreciate the help.  The file I want to copy is located in `C:\Users\Desktop\Test\` but will have a different file name every time.

```
foreach($folder in Get-Content "I:\foldername.txt")
{
  copy-item C:\Users\Desktop\Test\ -Destination \\servername\folder1\$Folder
}
```

error I'm getting is "Copy-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '\Scott1'."

Comment: So what's the question? With what exactly do you need help?

Comment: The script is not working, getting error "Copy-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '\Scott1'."

Answer (score 0):

its been a week but i think i have somewhat of an answer, you'll just need to change the paths and locations.

First, Copying one file to multiple folders, what i have done is made a text document with the literal paths (c:\users\blah\blah\content.txt with NO ""), then used this:

```
 $Folders = Get-Content "C:\Users\Andre\Desktop\Folder Names.txt"

 Foreach ($Folder in $Folders){
 Copy-Item "C:\Users\Andre\Downloads\test\Copying\File to copy.txt" -Destination 
 $Folder -Verbose}
```

Then i made this one for multiple files copying to multiple locations.

```
$Folders = Get-Content "C:\Users\Andre\Desktop\Folder Names.txt"
Foreach ($Folder in $Folders){
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "C:\Users\Andre\Desktop\Copying" | Copy-Item -Destination 
$Folder -Force -Container}
```